# Setup encrypted LVM with another OS installed

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 Server and have followed some guides as to how to achieve such (usually it includes cryptsetup, lvcreate and others) but I always get stuck on the first boot.

My system will not boot because either it can't find logical volumes or the volume group, I have also tried setting up an encrypted LVM using the installer by setting up the LVM and then encryption but I get the error that the system couldn't find the volumes for / and swap.

I also have Windows on another partition which prevents me from using the third option on the installer (use all disk and install encrypted LVM). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!